# RPM Operating System Binary Compatibility

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, opensuse, distribution-choice

When I read through the differences between CentOS, OpenSUSE, and Fedora, they frequently say that CentOS and Redhat are binary compatible.

My experience has been (Debian/Ubuntu) that regardless of distro, binary files will run and packages are compatible if they use the same package manager.

So why do these articles emphasize that CentOS and Redhat are binary compatible or are my assumptions wrong?

Comment: You're question isn't clear, can you rephrase this? Are you asking if CentOS & RHEL (Redhat Enterprise Linux) are compatible w/ OpenSUSE? Don't forget that there is also Fedora (Redhat's development distro) too.

Comment: Your assumption may be true for Debian/Ubuntu, since they share the same repositories. This is not true for RedHat, SLES or OpenSuSE. They may have different names for the same rpm-funtionality, or different versions with different compile-options...

Comment: @Nils that's the kind of information I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on @John Siu's answer the terminology is confusing if you're not familiar with the **Red Hat** technologies.

- **RHEL**      - Enterprise Linux (commercial version of Red Hat's OS)
- **CentOS**   - Community version of **RHEL** (binary compatible with **RHEL**)
- **Fedora**    - Bleeding edge OS built by the Fedora Project (Red Hat sponsored community proj.)
- **RPM**        - RPM Package Manager (formerly Red Hat Package Manager)

**NOTE:** `RPM` isn't a **Red Hat** only technology, **OpenSUSE** uses `RPMs` as well and these are not necessarily compatible with `RPMs` built for one of the 3 Red Hat based distros (**RHEL**, **CentOS**, or **Fedora**).

New technology usually shows up first in **Fedora** where it is worked out. **Fedora** distros usually have a shelf life of 13 months. At any time 2 releases are being actively supported, after which updating for it is dropped.

Once technologies have been proven out in **Fedora** they'll eventually show up in a release of **RHEL**. **RHEL's** shelf life is 10 years of production followed by 3 years of extended coverage. See [here](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/) for full details.

**CentOS** is a community project that is now sponsored by **Red Hat** but which is operated separately from **RHEL**. **CentOS** provides the same identical packages as **RHEL** with the **RHEL** branding stripped out and/or replaced with **CentOS** logos and branding. **CentOS** is sponsored by several customers that have very large numbers of computers but don't want to have to pay for a subscription of **RHEL** for each box. The **CentOS** project doesn't offer any support other than staying in lock step with updates as they come out for **RHEL**.

There are a lot of [other distros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:RPM-based_Linux_distributions) that make use of `RPMs` for package management. Some derive from **Red Hat** distros while other only make use of `RPM` the technology but are not compatible with **Red Hat** distros in any way, such as **openSUSE**.

Comment: You for completeness: Oracle Linux and Scientific Linux are RH-clones, too (also binary compatible to RH).

Comment: Yes if you check out the wikipedia link that I mentioned it includes all the RH derivatives). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aRPM-based_Linux_distributions

Answer (score 2):

CentOS and RedHat are binary compatible because CentOS is RedHat without the RedHat logo.

Quote from CentOS own [FAQ](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-d29a2b7e61ffc544973098f9dd49fe4663efba50)

> CentOS exists to provide a free enterprise class computing platform to anyone who wishes to use it. CentOS 5 and 6 are built from publicly available open source SRPMS provided by a prominent North American Enterprise Linux vendor, often referred to as "Upstream" or "The Upstream Vendor (TUV)". CentOS conforms fully with the upstream vendors redistribution policies and aims to be 100% binary compatible. (CentOS mainly changes packages to remove upstream vendor branding and artwork.). CentOS is designed for people who need an enterprise class OS without the cost or support of the prominent North American Enterprise Linux vendor. Neither the CentOS Project (we who build CentOS) nor any version of CentOS is affiliated with, produced by, or supported by the prominent North American Enterprise Linux vendor. Neither does our software contain the upstream vendor's product ... although it is built from the same open source SRPMS as the upstream enterprise products.

In [About CentOS](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=2), the ftp sources are listed

```
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Client/en/os/SRPMS
ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS
```

That `Upstream` is RedHat. That's why they are binary compatible.